# SharePoint 2013 on-prem Add-In EmailAssignTo on task list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-addin

I've created a Task List in my app web with a custom content type based on task. I want to be have an email sent when an item is assigned to someone.

Looking around it seems that adding EmailAssignTo="TRUE" to the List element in Schema.xml should do the trick however I see the following:
Warning 1 The 'EmailAssignTo' attribute is not declared.

EmailAssignTo doesn't seem to be documented by Microsoft.   Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick PowerShell check/test the List property you want appears to be entitled `EnableAssignToEmail`, which expects a Boolean value.

Source documentation from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enableassigntoemail.aspx

> SPList.EnableAssignToEmail property
>
> Gets or sets a Boolean value specifying whether e-mail notification is enabled for the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   I tried EnableAssignToEmail="TRUE" in the Schema.xml but see a similar warning when deploying:  Warning 1 The 'EnableAssignToEmail' attribute is not declared.

Comment: Are you adding it as an attribute on the <List> element or as a child element?

Comment: Also, are you saying it absolutely does not work, meaning you've deployed & tested it? Or is it just that VS is complaining? I'm seeing reports of other valid properties throwing the same warning but working just fine when deployed.

Comment: I'm adding EnableAssignToEmail as an attribute on the <List> element.    Have deployed to my dev site and packaged and tested on live site.   It just doesn't work.